# A href link to PHP file in PHP echo doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I have created a table called menu and two of its columns are menu_option and menu_content. What I want to do is, after I click on a menu_option to go to a separate .php file i created, which is supposed to show in a div the menu_content.

I still haven't figured out why when I click on it, it tells me that the object cannot be found.

```
<?php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>";    
            echo "<a href=\"menucontent.php\">";
            echo $row['menu_option']; 
            echo '</a>';
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

At first I thought this could work and in my menucontent.php I could use echo $row['menu_content']; to print the proper menu content for the menu option.

I would really apreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure the menucontent.php file is in the correct directory?

Comment: As all your links will go to a PHP script called `menucontent.php`, there's no difference between any of the entries in what they actually do when you click on the link.... what should each different menu option do? Do you mean `echo "<a href=\"" . $row['menu_content'] . "\">";`

Comment: my files are in the same directory.

Comment: I need each different menu option to allow me, after i click on it, to show or print on the page  the coresponding menu content, as i have saved them in my table

Comment: but this is the same file, not directory (menucontent.php)

Comment: No, sorry. The part of the code that I posted is saved in menu.php  and it's included in a <nav></nav>. So basically, this menu.php is a part of a header that I have. I have breaked my code in multiple files because I thought it would be easier to control the code. What I am trying to do is to create a menu, and when i click on a option of this menu, to go to a different page ( that's why I named it menucontent.php) that will show me the coresponding menu content of this $row['menu_option'].

Comment: The URL should be something like `menucontent.php?id=$row[id]`, so that clicking on the link sends the menu ID to the content script.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense and it's a good idea but for now, my problem is that when i click on the link, menucontent.php won't open and it says that the object is not found.

Comment: First of all, you use  `mysql_fetch_array`, so in `$row` the array will return in indexes, start from 0, 1, 2...so when you try `$row['some_string_value']`, the error was object not found. Try to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get a array with string keys. Second, do not use mysql, use mysqli or pdo. Third, like all other comments said,  all <a> tag will go to the same place "menucontent.php", you should do something different base on each id or menu_option

Comment: I don't think the real problem was using mysql_fetch_array, because $row['menu_option'] still showed me the menu options as I have it in the table, so atleast that is working. I think the problem is this line: echo "<a href=\"menucontent.php\">";   because no matter which menu option i click on, it doesnt redirect me to menucontent.php. I understood that I will have to use each id  for the specific menu option but for now i need to understand why it doesnt redirect me to menucontent.php

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Seeing the HTML code that is generated might help in understanding what is happening.

Comment: Hello. I have figured it out. Thank you all for the suggestions. I simply deleted the existing menucontent.php and created a new one. It worked. I replaced the a href link with  '<a href="menuc.php?id=' . $idaux . '">'   where $idaux = $row['menu_id']. In my new file menuc.php  i loop through the rows and when $row['menu_id'] === $_GET['id'] , i simply echo $row['menu_content'], which is what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Thank you all for the suggestions. I simply deleted the existing menucontent.php and created a new one. It worked. I replaced the a href link with '' where $idaux = $row['menu_id']. In my new file menuc.php i loop through the rows and when $row['menu_id'] === $_GET['id'] , i simply echo $row['menu_content'], which is what i wanted.